# How do I access the Resurgence Pack?

Tags: mass-effect-3, me3-resurgence-pack

The Resurgence pack was released today, and while I understand there's still some internal server issues preventing the new Weapons / Characters from being available, the new maps are already accessible, and folks are already playing and discussing them.

However, I can't seem to create a new game on one of the new maps, and setting it to random didn't make it turn up either. The content's *there*, so how do I access it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Despite needing to update Mass Effect 3 to run it, that patch was *not* the patch containing the Resurgence pack (as I had assumed). If you'd like to use the new maps (and eventually, weapons / characters), you need to actually access the DLC via "DLC" from the main menu - you can then "buy" the DLC for 0 BiowarePoints, afterwhich, it will install and be available for use in multiplayer.

Kinda convoluted, and not intuitive at all. (Especially since it's free - why not simply patch the game to add the content if *everyone* gets it?)

Comment: People wouldn't appreciate EA's kindness quite enough if they didn't have to jump through some hoops to get it.

Answer (score 0):

I too had problems with this.  I discovered by going to `System > Settings > Storage > Hard Drive > Games and Apps > Mass Effect 3` that the expansion downloads hadn't completely successfully for some reason.  They were marked with a big yellow exclamation mark and the details for them said they were incomplete.

I deleted these from my hard drive, went to the Game Marketplace and chose Download Again.  After the downloads had finished I booted the game back up and the maps and other expansion features were then available.